# banshee freezes the whole system

Tags: banshee

There is a problem after playing a **.mkv** file . After a couple of minutes it freezes the whole system, even you can't move the mouse. And the only way you can use the system again, is to turn off the system manually.I'm totally sure that there is no problem with the videos.

Is there any way to get rid of the problem?

Comment: Did you try using a different videoplayer, for example VLC?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a proper solution... I've run into freezes with Banshee too. I would second @M.Becerra 's suggestion of using VLC instead.

Comment: VLC on my system can't play this type of mkv file. It seems VLC doesn't support the codec(I've tried so many times to install the codec but I couldn't find the codec) .But I played the video on windows 7 with VLC and worked perfectly.